# Is there a way to authorize a script running through launchd to use the camera on MacOs

Tags: macos, camera, privacy, launchd

I wrote a script to take a picture with my webcam. I want it to run everytime I unlock my mac, so I created a `com.example.selfie.plist` file in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`. The sh script is working well from a terminal, my plist is working well when I just write text in a file, but I cannot make the imagesnap command to work through the plist file.

`selfie.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash 
datetime=$(date "+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") 
imagesnap -q -w 2 "/Users/taccle/Documents/Projets/Selfie/Photos/${datetime}.jpg"
```

`com.example.selfie.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.selfie</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/Users/taccle/Documents/Projets/Selfie/selfie.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
      <string>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.biometrickitd.plist</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

I suppose the issue is coming from Security and Privacy which doesn't allow launchd to access the camera (I'm not sure how I can get the logs when launchd scripts are running).

I found a workaround but I don't like it so much, my plist file calls `run_in_command_line.sh` which will open a terminal and then run `selfie.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"
    do script "/Users/taccle/Documents/Projets/Selfie/selfie.sh; exit"
end tell'
```

It's working well but I would prefer to have only one script and not starting a terminal like this. Do you know if there's any way to give my launchd access to the camera?

Comment: See if you can fix it with https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351632/is-there-command-to-grant-full-disk-access-for-specific-application

Comment: @taccle, curious if you got this fixed. I'm the author of imagesnap, and I'm trying to do the same thing to get a selfie whenever someone wakes up my laptop.  I can't get my Mac to grant permissions for the LaunchAgent.  The script runs fine from ~/.wakeup (using sleepwatcher) directly.

Comment: @rharder Nope, couldn't find another way than the workaround I described above. I don't have my mac any more, but next time I do, I'll have a look to sleepwatcher which seems to do what I wanted!